# not able to load a view when I disable javascript rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

Here is my controller code:-

```
def image_test
    respond_to do |format|
        format.js {render :layout => false}
        format.html {redirect_to image_test_path}
    end
end
```

I have got a partial by the name of _image_test.html.erb and and a simple view image_test.html.erb

In my routes I have done this:-

```
match "/image_test", :to => "/index#image_test"
```

It works fine when the javascript is enabled in the borwser however when I disable the javascript I want it to redirect me to my image_test.html.erb file. Instead I get a no route match error.

Please help me with this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a workaround for this solution which is giving the desired result of redirecting to another page if javascript is disabled in a browser but I do not know if this is the rails way.

I created empty action corresponding view for those actions and redirected to those views in case javascript is disabled.

Here is an example of what I did :-

```
def javascript_enabled_view
    respond_to do |format|
        format.js {render :layout => false}
        format.html {redirect_to :action => "javscript_disabled_view"}
    end
end
```

I have got a corresponding js.erb file and the partial for the above action which will work if javascript is enabled in the browser.

```
def javascript_disabled_view

end
```

I have got the corresponding html.erb file which will work in case javascript is disabled in the browser.

Thanks,